# AnyLogic: How to move agent presentations on upper agent's GIS map

Tags: gis, anylogic

I'm using AnyLogic 8.7.0 Professional with my project on Windows 10 for agent modeling.

I've place an agent (let's say `Bus`) with multiple agents (`Passenger`) 'inside' the `Bus`, and the `Bus` is directly presented on the GIS Map under the `Main` agent. The diagram of the agent level is as follow:

```
+ Projects
|- Main
|  |- Agents
|  |  |- bus
|  +- Presentation
|     |- level
|     |- map
|     +- bus_presentaion
|- Bus
|  |- Agents
|  |  +- passengers[..]
|  |- Presentation
|  |  +- passengers_presentaion
|  +- ...
|- Passenger
|  +- ...
```

When using `moveTo(lat, lon)` function with `Bus`, it can animate correctly on the GIS Map, while using `moveTo(lat, lon)` functon with `Passenger`, the `Passenger` only moves to the relative coordinates to the `Bus` in pixels rather than the specific (lat, lon) point on the GIS Map on the upper agent, which is `Main`.

I've tried switching the `Bus` agent's "Space and network - Space type" from 'Continuous' to 'GIS', and it turns out to create another GIS Map within the `Bus` agent. And the 'Visible on upper agent' in "Advanced - Visible" of the `passengers` population seems not to be the solution either.

How can I make the passenger animate on the GIS Map in the `Main` agent with specified GIS Route to a specific GIS Point without put `Passenger` directly in the `Main` Agent?

Answer (score 1):

you can't do what you want as you want it.

If the passengers live inside the bus, they will move in relation to the bus.

For them to move in relation to the GIS coordinates, they MUST live in Main.

What I would do is add an empty population of passengers in Main and when a passenger needs to move in the GIS you do

```
agent.goToPopulation(main.passengers);
```

When they go back to the bus, you can do

```
agent.goToPopulation(bus.passengers);
```